# Is it safe to split csv files using \n?

Tags: php, parsing, csv, explode

Is it safe to split csv files using the `\n` character using `explode()` or should I also include `\r` to be safe? 90% of the files will be coming from windows computers and probably converted from .xls files using ms excel.

Comment: You don't need to include `\r`. You can explode with just `\n`. However, it'd be good to do a `trim()` on the lines after exploding them.

Comment: @NADH Are you positive? Got anything on the manual to confirm this or any test?

Comment: Yes, I'm positive. Coming from experience. However, you should really be using `fgetscsv` than exploding lines manually. If you still don't want to do that, you can depend on `file()` that reads lines of a file into an array.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You want to use [fgetcsv](http://en.php.net/manual/en/function.fgetcsv.php)/[fgets](http://en.php.net/manual/en/function.fgets.php) in combination with [auto_detect_line_ending](http://www.php.net/manual/en/filesystem.configuration.php#ini.auto-detect-line-endings).

You need to count? Incrementing a counter in fgetcsv will you **save alot of ram** and (cpu)time instead of a complete read-in and a additional looping to count the read-in.

And also you will be more flexible if you change your mind and yet want to save a row or even particular cells for a later processing.

Answer (score 4):

Why aren't you using [`fgetcsv`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.fgetcsv.php) in the first place?

See the following note on that man page:

> **Note**: If PHP is not properly recognizing the line endings when reading files either on or created by a Macintosh computer, enabling the `auto_detect_line_endings` run-time configuration option may help resolve the problem.

Comment: Need to calculate and display the total number of lines in the file without looping through all lines. Right now I'm doing `$lines = explode()... $totalLines = count($lines);`

Comment: `$file = "somefile.txt"; $lines = count(file($file));`. Although @breiti has a point about RAM usage with methods like this.

Answer (score 1):

How about:

```
$num_lines = count(file('your-file.csv'));
```

Not sure how intensive this would be though?